# How to save core data with an xml parser

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xml-parsing

I made this xml parser :

XMLToObjectParser.m :

```
#import "XMLToObjectParser.h"

@implementation XMLToObjectParser

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)items
{
    return items;
}

- (id)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url
           toObject:(NSString *)aClassName
         parseError:(NSError **)error
{
    //[items release];
    items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    className = aClassName;
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    if([parser parserError] && error) {
        *error = [parser parserError];
    }
    //[parser release];
    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:className]) {
        // create an instance of a class on run-time
        item = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    }
    else {
        currentNodeName = [elementName copy];
        currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    //NSLog(@"Close tag: %@", elementName);
    if([elementName isEqualToString:className]) {
        [items addObject:item];
        //[item release];
        item = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:currentNodeName]) {
        // use key-value coding
        [item setValue:currentNodeContent forKey:elementName];

        //[currentNodeContent release];
        currentNodeContent = nil;

        //[currentNodeName release];
        currentNodeName = nil;
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //[items release];
    //[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

XMLToObjectParser.h :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLToObjectParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    NSString *className;
    NSMutableArray *items;
    NSObject *item; // stands for any class
    NSString *currentNodeName;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSArray *)items;
- (id)parseXMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url
           toObject:(NSString *)aClassName
         parseError:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

It's parsing a xml like this :

```
<section id="2">
  <label>Animaux</label>
  <image>Images/Rayons/Bandeau/Animaux.png</image>
  <key>Images/Rayons/Bandeau/Animaux.png</key>
  <products>
     <Product id="21">
        <category_id>Chat</category_id>
        <label>Aliments pour chat</label>
        <price>2.00</price>
     </Product>
     <Product id="1286">
        <category_id>Chat</category_id>
        <label>Boite de paté</label>
        <price>0.00</price>
     </Product>
  </products>
</sections>
```

But it crashes on the line

```
 item = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't read all code posted, but I think you're looking for this method:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name
                     inManagedObjectContext:ctx];
```

`+entityForName:` only gets the entity description (of type `NSEntityDescription`) but you're trying to create an object.

Comment: Yes, but how to get ctx from my xmlParser Class? Sorry, but i am starting with objective C.

Comment: Where in your code is your `NSManagedObjectContext` allocated?

Comment: I put it in my Parser.h , the truth is that i created a project without core data, i maybe forgot something.

Comment: ouch.. just create a new project, saves a lot of headaches, especially if you are just starting...

Comment: Hello, i tried it but i still have an error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Section''

Comment: Did you check if the managed object context you're passing to `+entityForName` is not nil?

Comment: So you found your problem. At some point in your code, you allocate an `NSManagedObjectContext`. Your problem is that you need a reference to this context, and use it in the `+entityForName` call. E.g. by adding it as an extra argument to your `parseXMLAtURL` method.

Comment: I accepted your answer but can you tell me what is the best way to get my NSManagedObjectContext ?

Comment: I believe the boilerplate code creates the context in the app delegate. That's where you should get it from, e.g. using `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]` This is not necessarily the "best" way, but it should at least get you going.